# How to test jest + sequelize?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

Good evening, i trying write integration tests.
But, i stuck with database, when i do `sequelize.sync({ force: true })`, i get some errors, it works random.

now, all my tests looks like this:

```js
const CategoryModel = require('../CategoryModel'); // sequelize model

beforeAll(async () => {
  await CategoryModel.sync({ force: true });
  await CategoryModel.bulkCreate([ /* data for insert */ ]);
});

// then there are tests
```

Sequelize behaving strange, throw errors random:

```js
1. bulkCreate() - [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Table 'shop_test.categories' does not exist
2. bulkCreate() - [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError]: Validation error. (Duplicate entry 'spoons' for key 'categories.slug')
```

How is this possible?
Because `.sync()` method with `{ force: true }` drop table and then create new one, using schema

i run jest with options:

```json
"test": "jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to run a setup file with jest. For instance, this setup file initializes the database. https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array